# wxpython set max textbox value length

Tags: wxpython

how i can set the max character length of the textbox in wxpython?

```
import wx
from wx.lib.masked import NumCtrl
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,id,title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,title)
        self.panelMain = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        panel = self.panelMain
    
   
        #creating buttons and text boxes.
        self.guessTxt = wx.lib.masked.NumCtrl(self.panelMain,-1,size=(100,20),pos=(50,102))
        self.newGameTxt = wx.TextCtrl(self.panelMain,-1,size=(100,20),pos=(180,73))
```

as seen at this line

```
self.newGameTxt = wx.TextCtrl(self.panelMain,-1,size=(100,20),pos=(180,73))
```

im creating the textbox, but how can i set the max characters it can contain?

Answer (score 0):

self.newGameTxt.SetMaxLength(200)

http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/TextEntry.html?highlight=maxl#TextEntry.SetMaxLength